# google sheets filter formula before and equal to date not including last date

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a formula to filter data before and equal to a date, however it is including every date up to and not including that one. What am I doing wrong? The formula:

`=FILTER(A:F,F:F>=C8,F:F<=D8)`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `F:F` to

```
arrayformula(int(F:F))
```

you probably have also hours in column F